# Returning A Custom Object From XMLHttpRequest Object

Tags: javascript

I am returning an "Employee" object from my javascript ajax call..

```
var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhReq.open("POST", "MobileClientService.svc/REST/TestReturnEmployee", false);
xhReq.send(null);

var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
```

What is returned is JSON data. I would like to return an Object that has the structure of my Employee object so I could write in javascript..

```
var name = serverResponse.Name;
```

Is this possible to do or is my only choise to parse the returned JSON string? No I cant use jquery (it returns the object fine that way) it must be javascript only.

Comment: Question is not very clear. But seems like you already know the answer. If you echo a JSON string, you will have to parse it before accessing the object's properties.

Comment: So in jquery you can get an object back like the structure of your server side object but in regular javascript you cant?

Comment: jQuery does the parsing automatically for you when it expects a JSON response. Maybe you should try [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse): `var response = JSON.parse(responseText); var name = response.Name;`

Comment: If that doesn't help, include the result of a `console.log(responseText)` in the question to see what you're getting.

Comment: @Fabricio That worked thank you. Set it as an annswer so I can credit you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery automatically parses the `responseText` into an object when it expects a JSON response.

In vanilla JS, you can parse it with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var response = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText),
    name = response.Name;
```

Include this library also if you need compatibility with IE<=7: [Crockford's JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

---

### About `eval`

It's also possible to use `eval` to parse the `responseText` string into an object to have compatibility with IE<=7 as well without including extra code, but `eval` is evil.

Of course, if your server always echoes well-formed JSON, it wouldn't be a problem. I'd personally avoid `eval` and use the proper `JSON.parse`, but if you want to use `eval` for the IE<=7 compatibility without including extra code you can do it as follows:

```
var response = eval('(' + xhReq.responseText + ')'),
    name = response.Name;
```